# How do the connections from V1 to V2 form during early development of the human brain?

Tags: neuroscience, visual-system, development

I am wondering how corticocortical efferents from layer I and II in V1 develop to forward visual information to layer IV in V2. Is there topology preservation in these connections from the beginning on or does it only emerge later?